# Customized navigation bar does not receive touch events in entire view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to implement this [image of my implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb51o.jpg).

Where the three buttons below the uilabel are clickable. I have one UIView as a subview of my custom navigation bar view, then two views within that view, one is the uilabel and the second is the uiview of uibuttons i

I've tried implementing solutions from other answers like

```
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if self.point(inside: point, with: event) {
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }else{
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
}
```

But that didn't work. I noticed that if I tapped above the button near the position of the default uinavigation bar size then the tap is recognized.

The size of my navigation bar is `CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 100)` if that helps.

**Update**

just adding my custom navigation class and it's usage

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    let newSize :CGSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 100)
    return newSize
}

override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if self.point(inside: point, with: event) {
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }else{
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
}
```

}

```
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: CustomNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)
    navigationController.setViewControllers([mainController], animated: false)

    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the problem!**

The view, which contained the title and buttons, was set with a frame with a height of 60 instead of the height of my custom navigation bar. Thanks for the help guys.

**Lesson here was**

After setting custom height for navigation bar make sure it's subView's bounds matches the navigation bar's bounds.

Comment: Hey, Can you post some code for the solution. I am stuck in the same problem, I tried to customize navigation bar but somehow couldn't trigger clicks on any buttons inside the custom view

Comment: Hi Shivam, I don't have access to the code anymore but if the problem you are facing is exactly like the one I faced then you should set the views' clipsToBounds property to true to help debug.

Comment: Hi Woody, Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to resolve the issue, it had something to do with the autolayout constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Please check that your navigation bar height was increased or not, that will be the reason stoping complete interaction of Navigation bar, Add following code and check will work fine,

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let height: CGFloat = 100 //whatever height you want
    let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)

}
```

Comment: Hey Manikanta, I've tried your suggestion and that did not work.

Comment: Can you please share your code of customising navigation bar.

Comment: I've updated my question with my custom class and how I used it.

Comment: in your mainController's viewDidAppear, please write above code and check once.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should change the navigationbar frame in viewdidappear only otherwise frame will not effect.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:width, height:  height)
```